# INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE in Cordova based app

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I am trying to develop an app for android using cordova.I am facing an issue of low memory when trying to run the app on emulator.I tried the followings to fix the issue ,but still no luck

1 . Changed the partition size to 1024 
2 . Given the Internal storage size as 1000 Mib

Evenif i gave the internal storage size as 1000MiB ,in the emulator settings the internal storage size is showing as 200 Mb only.Please advice .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Remove and setup new emulator or just uninstall unnecessary application form that emulator

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I tried this also...but no luck

Comment: Provide here emulator configuration details

Comment: Device : Galaxy Nexus Target : android 4.4.2 Memory options : RAM-1024 VM Heap - 64 Internal Storage : 1024MiB SD Card Size : 1024MiB